# how to convert c# function to php

Tags: c#, php, mysql

How do I convert a C# function to a PHP function?  The C# code is below:

```
internal string EncodePassword(string password, string salt)
{
       // Get the Unicode bytes of the plain text password.
       byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password);

       // The salt is a Base64 encoded string, convert back to a byte array.
       byte[] src = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);

       // Concat both byte buffers.
       byte[] dst = new byte[src.Length + bytes.Length];
       byte[] inArray = null;
       System.Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 0, dst, 0, src.Length);
       System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, dst, src.Length, bytes.Length);

       // Compute the SHA1-hash from the concatenated buffer.
       System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1 algorithm = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed.Create();
       inArray = algorithm.ComputeHash(dst);

       // Return the result as a Base64-string.
       return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);
}
```

Comment: Can you insert the code in a code block ?

Comment: I think your question is not How to convert? Your question is can you  please convert it to php :))

Comment: first you should know the password hashing functions of php

Answer (score 4):

I know its too late to answer this question. But i think it will be helpful for someone who is trying to convert C# code to PHP. I had a similar kind of requirement recently

```
<?php

$password ='test123';
$salt = '5Br2nXb56EpliGXmfHdWWw==';

$password = mb_convert_encoding($password,'UTF-16LE');
echo base64_encode(sha1(base64_decode($salt).$password,true));
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd say it's something like this:

```
function encodePassword($password, $salt){
  return base64_encode(sha1($password . base64_decode($salt), true));
}
```

Comment: Possibly `sha1(…, true)`. Otherwise I agree, it *seems* like that's all it's doing.

Comment: Yes, should be `true` as the second `sha1()`-parameter... (changed the answer accordingly).

Comment: Just for explanation: the C# SHA1 will be returned as raw bytes while PHP's SHA1 returns a hex string by default (`true` changes this behavior)

Comment: i have a salt value "5Br2nXb56EpliGXmfHdWWw==" and password "test123" and i have c# genrated password witch is using above salt and password the password is:- "YmwXST4800UkXas17GBEXex+mYQ=" can you do this in php thanks in advance :))

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP [SHA1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php) function to do the encryption.

Comment: YES I CAN BUT NOT GET THE RESULT ALSO PLEASE SEE THIS:- i have a salt value "5Br2nXb56EpliGXmfHdWWw==" and password "test123" and i have c# genrated password witch is using above salt and password the password is:- "YmwXST4800UkXas17GBEXex+mYQ=" can you do this in php thanks in advance :))